# How to find out which CGRect is closest from array?

Tags: swift

I have an array of `[CGRect]`.
CGRect has x, y, width, height

I also have a `CGPoint`.
CGPoint has x, y.

How would i know which is the first frame in the array that is closest to the point?

I know how to do this with single values.
But not with a x, y, width & height

Where do I begin? I am ok with just a description of what to do.

Comment: Can any of the rects contain the point? If two rects contain the point, how do you determine which is closer?

Comment: Sorry, for the late response. It was late here. Its mentioned in the question above. But if two rects contain the point, i will just choose the first rect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to figure out what Rob asked. One option is [signed distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function) comparison.

[Video: Deriving the SDF of a Box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62-pRVZuS5c)

If multiple rectangles contain the point, the "closest" one will be the one whose closest edge to the point is farthest away, i.e. where the point is "more contained".

```swift
rects.min { [point = SIMD2(point)] in point.getSignedDistance(to: $0) }
```

```swift
public extension CGRect {
  var center: CGPoint { .init(x: midX, y: midY) }
}
```

```swift
public protocol CGFloat2 {
  var x: CGFloat { get }
  var y: CGFloat { get }
}

extension CGPoint: CGFloat2 { }

extension CGSize: CGFloat2 {
  public var x: CGFloat { width }
  public var y: CGFloat { height }
}
```

```swift
import simd

public extension SIMD2 where Scalar == CGFloat.NativeType {
  init<Float2: CGFloat2>(_ float2: Float2) {
    self.init(x: float2.x, y: float2.y)
  }

  init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
    self.init(x: x.native, y: y.native)
  }

  /// Distance to the closest point on the rectangle's boundary.
  /// - Note: Negative if inside the rectangle.
  func getSignedDistance(to rect: CGRect) -> Scalar {
    let distances =
      abs( self - Self(rect.center) )
      - Self(rect.size) / 2
    return
      all(sign(distances) .> 0)
      ? length(distances)
      : distances.max()
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  func min<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    by getComparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable
  ) rethrows -> Element? {
    try self.min {
      try getComparable($0) < getComparable($1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: given the clarification i made in the comments above, will your solution work? I looked at the wiki link, but the math there much too complex for me to understand.

Comment: I added a second paragraph. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Do you mean your min extension makes the calculation more efficient?  Or are you saying that it I should remove the extension all together. I am still here trying to digest the answer.

Comment: That `min` extension is unnecessary and complicates your answer... You could  directly use `min { $0.signedDistance < $1.signedDistance }`. Sorry for my previous comments, your code confused me.

Comment: I don't think that's true at all, and obviously I think this overload should be in the standard library.

Comment: I am not saying that extension is bad. I am saying that it is not a necessary part of the answer.

Comment: I think it is, but I did edit my answer after thinking about what you said. (The distance itself probably isn't necessary to include in the result.) Thanks!

Comment: Ignore that last comment. My bad.